# How do you run windows explorer as a different user?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, windows-explorer, runas

I can't believe this question wasn't already asked. I came across the answer when asking a slightly different question.

Lets say I am logged in as user Bob and I open up a command prompt via the [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command with Alice's credentials. How do I launch explorer with Alice's credentials from the command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Florin Lazar](http://blogs.msdn.com/drapp/default.aspx) answered this question in this [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/florinlazar/archive/2005/09/17/470001.aspx). You launch explorer as follows:

```
explorer/separate
```

If anyone has a better answer, I'll wait a bit before marking mine as the accepted answer.

Comment: there's a runas.exe component to this: runas /user:myComputerordomain\administrator "explorer /separate"

Comment: It works, and the process running is explore.exe (not iexplore.exe), even though it states "Microsoft Internet Explorer" in the title bar.

Comment: @shufler I understand I can skip the command prompt via a direct runas command. However, thats a good point for anyone looking this up.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to configure explorer so that all folders windows are separate processed for that user. To do that launch explorer as the user you want to be able to run explorer as through the [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command then select "Tools | Folder Options". From there check the box labeled "Launch folder windows in separate process," as shown below.

[image: Launch folder windows in separate process]